# CSS absolute positioned elements make underneath inputs unclickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, absolute

The HTML and CSS:

```css
#iphone_container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    z-index: 0;
}
#iphone {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    max-height: 75vh;
}
#contact__address {
    padding: 2vh 10vh;
    background-color: rgba(48, 60, 81, 0.67);
    opacity: 0.67;
}
#contact__address p {
    color: white;
}
#contact__iphone_picto {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    max-width: 35%;
}
#iphone_screen {
    position: absolute;
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #BAC8E0);
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#iphone_nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #91A2CC;
    padding: 1vh 2vh;
}
#iphone_nav img {
    max-width: 3vh;
}
#iphone_nav a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1vh;
}
#iphone_content {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 40%;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 5;
}
#iphone_content form * {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="iphone_container">
    <img src="images/body/Structure Iphone transparente.png" id="iphone" unselectable="on">
    <div id="iphone_screen">
        <img src="images/body/Contact.png" id="contact__iphone_picto">
        <div id="iphone_content">
            <form class="text-center">
                <label for="nom">Nom</label>
                <input type="text" name="nom">
                <label for="prenom">Prénom</label>
                <input type="text" name="prenom">
                <label for="Email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email">
                <label for="telephone">Téléphone</label>
                <input type="tel" name="telephone">
            </form>
        </div>
        <nav class="d-flex text-center" id="iphone_nav">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="images/body/Icone Accueil blanc.png">
                <a href="#">Accueil</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="images/body/Icone Plan blanc.png">
                <a href="#">Plan</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <img src="images/body/Icone Contact blanc.png">
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

"Structure Iphone transparente.png" -> https://ibb.co/BKP0nTN

I'm designing a static iPhoneUI-like in pure CSS, everything is almost correctly placed, but the problem is that I can't click on my inputs or anything inside my #iphone_screen div (like the `nav` a).
I know this is relative to z-indexes, I can solve it by lowering `#iphone z-index`, and increase #iphone_screen's one, but since this div has a background-color, the background-color just go onto the iPhone Structure `img` and we miss the point of building such a thing.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: `#iphone {pointer-events: none;}` might solve your issue.

Comment: Move `background-color` to another element and change z-indexs

Comment: Hey @ww0k - following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" *(by clicking the checkmark beside the answer)* to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). Remember, too: you can upvote any answers you found helpful (you can also upvote and checkmark the same answer, if desired.) *Thanks!*

Comment: @ww0k This question is still open. Please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 3):

If you know the id/className of the element that is sitting atop of the input field(s), you can use the css property `pointer-events:none` to fix your problem.

You would place the `pointer-events:none` css directive on any element that blocks or partially blocks an underlying element - *with the proviso that you will not then be able to click on those elements (the ones with `pointer-events:none` on them)*. Usually, those are `h1` or `p` or `div` or etc that don't require user input, but *be warned* about this.

`pointer-events:none` tells the browser to pass any click events through the element to underlying elements. So, an overlay div that is 100vw/100vh will normally prevent users from interacting with anything underneath - but `pointer-events:none` will allow users to click buttons and enter inputs that would normally be blocked by the overlay.

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events